# Trouble locating element

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath

I'm testing an application and in the application there is a table containing checkboxes (3 rows, x columns). Below is the html for part of this table (1row). I'm trying to click on the text of one of these items to either select or deselect a checkbox based on the text. So for example, I want to click on the text 'Text next to checkbox for nr 8' in order to select that textbox. However, I don't want to go there via a hard xpath using code like /table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/span)[2] but based on the text. I'm trying code like the ones below but they don't seem to work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='settingsPanelTD' and text()='Text next to checkbox for nr 8']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='settingswidgetTitle' and text()='Text next to checkbox for nr 8']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='settingswidgets' and text()='Text next to checkbox for nr 8']")).click();
```

I would like to create a string for the final xpath so you only have to change the text you'd like to click to change the test, something like:

```
String text = "Text next to checkbox for nr 8"; /** variable text based on what you want to click */
String locator = "//*[@class='settingswidgets' and text()='";
String xpathitem = locator + text + "']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathitem)).click();
```

This is the HTML:

```
<td class="settingsPanelTD" width="33%">
<div class="settingwidgetsTitle">
    <input id="widgetsettings8" class="settingwidgets" type="checkbox" alt="2">
    <span>Text next to checkbox for nr 8</span>
    <a class="AddWidget" href="#"></a>
</div>
</td>
<td class="settingsPanelTD" width="33%">
<div class="settingwidgetsTitle">
    <input id="widgetsettings9" class="settingwidgets" type="checkbox" alt="2">
    <span>Text next to checkbox for nr 9</span>
    <a class="AddWidget" href="#"></a>
</div>
</td>
<td class="settingsPanelTD" width="33%">
<div class="settingwidgetsTitle">
    <input id="widgetsettings9" class="settingwidgets" type="checkbox" alt="2">
    <span>Text next to checkbox for nr 10</span>
    <a class="AddWidget" href="#"></a>
</div>
</td>
```

I'm using eclipse, Selenium and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPaths you are using are incorrect. The third XPath you are using is closest to the correct solution:

```
//*[@class='settingswidgets' and text()='Text next to checkbox for nr 8']
```

In plain English, your XPath means - look for any element in the document with a `class="settingswidgets"` and text equal to `Text next to checkbox for nr 8`. Unfortunately, no such element exists.

One potential XPath you could use is:

```
//span[text()="Text next to checkbox for nr 8"]
```

This searches for any `span` element with the appropriate text.

You could then use:

```
String text = "Text next to checkbox for nr 8";
String locator = "//span[text()='";
String xpathitem = locator + text + "']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathitem)).click();
```

This should generate the desired click.

Comment: Thanks! that worked like a charm. Didn't know you could use span text too. Still new at this and learning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add comment 
but in case you are unable to select option by clicking Span tag you need to click on input tag

`ArrayList<WebElement> al=new ArrayList<WebElement>();`
        `driver.findElements(By.className("settingwidgetsTitle"));`

`for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){`
`if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='settingwidgetsTitle']/span")).getText().equals("Option to Select")){`

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='settingwidgetsTitle']["+i+"]`
`/input").click());`
`break;`
`}}`